# Scanning large text file into NetBeans

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, file, netbeans

For some reason, NetBeans only reads in the first 1000 lines into the String array, and the rest of the array is left null. If I run the code in Eclipse it works. I've tried increasing the heap size, but it hasn't worked. Here is the code for reference.

```
private String[] loadDictionary() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String[] darr = new String[10000];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Dictionary"));
    for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++)    
    {
        if(sc.hasNext())
            darr[i] = sc.next();
    }
    sc.close();
    return darr;
}
```

Comment: Hard for me to belive it. How do you know that there are only 1000 lines read?

Comment: If I do System.out.print(darr[999]), it outputs a word within the file, but System.out.print(darr[1000]) gives null.

Comment: Check with a debugger if `sc.hasNext()` is true after 1000 reads.

Comment: Printing out sc.hasNext() is no longer true after 1000 reads, which is confusing as the file it is connected to contains 10000 lines.

Comment: Then check the last read item from the array and then check the file if there is something odd after that word. Maybe a different whitespace?

Comment: I checked the last item read, but curiously the word is not on line 1000, but line 4094. There are no breaks after that word. The second to last read word occurs on line 3616 in the file.

Comment: *"the word is not on line 1000, but line 4094"* You're not reading lines, you're reading "words" (mind the diff between `next` and `nextLine`). But it is still odd, that it is on that line. So you should check which "words" are read as one (on one single index) even though they should have been splitted. You may find some interessting stuff on the whitespace between them.

Comment: To clarify, the file that I'm trying to read contains 1 word per line. Using a for loop to print out the last 100 lines read, which contain 1 word per line as intended. However, it did reveal words throughout the entire 10000 word file. Any idea why these words are out of order?

Comment: I've moved all my classes into a new Package, and it seems to have fixed the issue. No idea what was causing the error, but for now it's been solved. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: *"However, it did reveal words throughout the entire 10000 word file."* What do you mean with that? It is quite unclear. // Is it possible that you actually ran an older version, due to a missing rebuild after a code change?

Comment: It seemed like it had randomly selected lines from the entire file. If I had been running an old version, then reconstructing the package may have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` insteed.

Comment: Stuff like "try this" and "try that" should be a comment, if there is no explanation why your suggestion (may) solves OPs problem.